# SQL count where where column is greater than the other in group by?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table `money_table` like:

```
team_id | money_spent | money_budget
--------------------------------------
123     |  3456.32    | 3466
964     |  236.32     | 200
123     |  9663       | 9400
964     |  3456.32    | 3466
```

The output table should be:

```
team_id | total_money_spent | total_money_budget | days_over_spent | days_under_spent
--------------------------------------
123     |  13119.32         | 12866              |  2              |    0
964     |  3692.64          | 3666               |  1              |.   1
```

The first 2 columns are easy with a group BY, I am wondering about the last 2 columns and how to tackle that. My initial query was:

```
SELECT 
 team_id,
 SUM(money_spent) as total_money_spent,
 SUM(money_budget) as total_money_budget
FROM money_table
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY team_id ASC
```

The works fine for the first 2 columns, but I am unable to think of how to get `days_over_spent` and `days_under_spent`.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

`days_over_spent` is the number of rows where `money_spent > money_budget`

`days_under_spent` is the number of rows where `money_spent < money_budget`

Comment: How do you calculate days_over_spent and days_under_spent?

Comment: @forpas, basically any time `money_spent` was grater than `money_budget` for `days_over_spent` and vice-versa for underspent

Comment: @JonnyHenly added update edit

Comment: @forpas added edit

Comment: Then why is days_over_spent = 2 for team_id = 123?

Comment: @forpas because I did a  calculation, sorry thats wrong.

Comment: What is, if `money_spent == money_budet` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 team_id,
 SUM(money_spent) as total_money_spent,
 sum(money_budget) as total_money_budget,
 sum(case when money_spent > money_budget then 1 else 0 end) as days_over_spent,
 sum(case when money_spent < money_budget then 1 else 0 end) as days_under_spent
FROM money_table
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY team_id ASC
```

Comment: `COUNT` will count the rows in a group, so with the given example data `total_money_buget` and `days_over_spent`  will be always  `2` You may want to use `SUM` for all 4 calculated columsn

Answer (score 1):

You could do the calculations for "over the budget" in a CTE

```
with tmp (t, s, b, o, u) as (
  select 
    team, 
    spent, 
    budget,
    case when spent > budget then 1 else 0 end,
    case when spent < budget then 1 else 0 end
  from budget
  )
    
select 
  t as team, 
  sum(s) as total_spent,
  sum(b) as total_budget, 
  sum(o) as days_over, 
  sum(u) as days_under
from tmp
group by t
```

Of course you can also just add the case into the query itself

```
  select 
    team, 
    sum(spent), 
    sum(budget),
    sum(case when spent > budget then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when spent < budget then 1 else 0 end)
  from budget
  group by team
```